# REFIT: Howto ignore class properties while composing query

Tags: c#, .net-core, refit

I have this problem I don't see a way out: I want refit to ignore some public property while composing a query.

Let's say I have this class

```
public class TestClass {
    [AliasAs("myprop1")]
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    [AliasAs("myprop2")]
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    public string Prop3 {get; set;}
    public string Prop4 {get; set;}
}
```

and this interface

```
public interface IMyClient {
    [Get("/login")]
    public Task<ApiResponse<TestClass>> Login(string username, string password);

    [Get("/verify")]
    public Task<ApiResponse<TestClass>> Check(TestClass myClass);
}
```

When I call `var resp = client.Login("user", "test");` API is called properly and I get the desired result.
For this reason I need all of the properties of TestClass to be public, or when deserializing the response some property would be ignored.

Next when I call `var resp = client.Verify(resp.Content)` I'd need only `Prop1` and `Prop2` to be passed to the API call.
Making `Prop3` and `Prop4` private is not a way, because I need them when calling `Login`.
I've searched for some REFIT attribute, but (my bad) I couldn't find any.

I could even split my class in one interface having just `Prop1` and `Prop2` and a class implementing that interface with the additional properties, but I hope there could be a simpler solution.

Is there a way to use the very same model?

Comment: Refit solves 1 problem and gives you 2 more and paints you into a corner for the rest of the design

Comment: @TheGeneral I've always worked with RestSharp, but I've seen some good tutorial on Refit, so I decided to give it a try. Then read the GitHub project page and seemed very powerful and easy... and at the very beginning it was. Then I found myself into this problem that should be easy to solve... I thought it should be easy, but probably no :(

Comment: I'd say that the signature of `Check` is misleading, since api doesn't really expect or need `TestClass`. Using any kind of attributes on `TestClass` properties to circumvent that seems not like a good idea. What if you had third api which expected another set of properties in the `TestClass`, will you reuse it there too? I'd just use proper class with only the required properties for `Check` request.

Comment: @evk speaks the truth. Though, in all honestly the tooling is good for vanilla designs and simplistic apis as a lot of things in this world, its every other use case you need narrow your design (which is usually a good thing) or just plumb it up with standard modern http plumbing where you have access to everything, take the developer debt and have full control... in short, your use case is not supported, you will need to rethink your design

Comment: @evk you're right and so TheGeneral. I'm just playing with this new library (to me) to discover what cna be done and how. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Just add the attribute `[JsonIgnore]` above the property you don't want to include in the query.
Depending on which serialiser you have, it may be either the one from `System.Text.Json` (the default serialiser for Refit) or the one from `Newtonsoft.Json`.

In your example

```
public class TestClass {
    [AliasAs("myprop1")]
    public string Prop1 {get; set;}
    [AliasAs("myprop2")]
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop3 {get; set;}
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Prop4 {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: No I can't: I need both Prop3 and Prop4 to be public and returned in the response for the Login call

Comment: The thing is that you don't want the same request object as the response object. Then make a separate class with prop1 and prop2 and use that class as the request object, then make your test class inherit that class with prop3 and prop4, you don't need an interface for that.